# Proper Way to Reference Variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, reference

I'm currently refactoring my code and I want to export an object array called `REFERENCE_LIST` to another file.

reference.js

```
export const REFERENCE_LIST = [
 {name:"TypeA", foodList:foodAList}, 
 {name:"TypeB", foodList:foodBList}
]

export const foodAList = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']
];

export const foodBList = ['meat', 'fish']
];
```

However, the `foodList` field from `REFERENCE_LIST` is always "undefined".  Am I referencing these arrays incorrectly?

Comment: yes the console is right because foodList was never declared or assigned so it remains undefined when you are trying to use it.

Comment: And the reason why the name field works is because it is a normal string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot *reference* variables in JS. You can reference object values, though - but those objects need to be created first for that:

```
export const foodAList = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana'];
export const foodBList = ['meat', 'fish'];

export const REFERENCE_LIST = [
  {name:"TypeA", foodList:foodAList}, 
  {name:"TypeB", foodList:foodBList}
];
```

You might also use getters where the order of creation doesn't matter:

```
export const REFERENCE_LIST = [
  {name:"TypeA", get foodList() { return foodAList; }}, 
  {name:"TypeB", get foodList() { return foodBList; }}
];
```

But even those will throw an exception when you evaluate them before the constants are initialised.